# how to join 2 table on Hibernate in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, hql

i need help. i want to ask about Hibernate HQL on grails. i want to join 2 tables into 1 result.

My Controller

`TRANSACTION.executeQuery("from TRANSACTION join SUBSCRIBER on TRANSACTION.subscriberID = SUBSCRIBER.msisdn where TRANSACTION.date = '2020-09-04'"`

result: unexpected token: on

when i change my code same like this source
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466398/how-to-do-a-simple-table-join-in-grails)

`TRANSACTION .executeQuery("from TRANSACTION t1,SUBSCRIBER t2 where t1.subscriberID = t2.msisdn and TRANSACTION.date = '2020-09-04'")`

result :  Unknown column 'subscriber0_.pos' in 'field list'

My DB Mapping

```
class Transaction implements Validateable{
String id
String subscriberID
String currentBalance 
String date

static mapping = {
    datasource 'trx'
    table 'TRANSACTION'
    id generator: 'assigned', column: "ID"
    subscriberID column: "subscriberID"  <-- this value is equals to msisdn at Subscriber
    currentBalance column: "currentBalance"
    date column: "date" 
    version false
}
```

---

```
class Subscriber implements Validateable{

String id   
String msisdn
String firstName

static mapping = {
    datasource 'subs'
    table 'SUBSCRIBER'
    
    id column:"subscriberID"        
    msisdn column:"msisdn"      
    firstName column:"firstName"

    version false
    
}
```

i want to join them like this

| firstName | subscriberID | currentBalance | Date |

Comment: Add leading `select *` to the query and retry

Comment: @MarmiteBomber i got a result like this:
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from com.dm.voucher.Transaction where date = '2020-09-04'];

Comment: Oh sorry, apparently the [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/queryhql-joins.html) queries do not need an *explicite* `ON` join clause - see examples in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/queryhql-expressions.html)

Comment: hai @MarmiteBomber i just read inner join and i make my code into this

def query= "from Transaction trx, Subscriber subs "
query= query+"inner join subs.msisdn where "
query = query +"Transaction.subscriberID = '0'"
query= Transaction.executeQuery(query); 

and i got this : org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.ArrayList'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it!

def query = "select table1.subscriberID,table2.msisdn from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id"
query= table1.executeQuery(query);